# networkx best practice getting edge attribute value while iterating over edges

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

Given a list of edges (or a generator). What is the most readable way to identify edges with a certain attribute value? For example all edges with an 'edge_type' of 'foo'?

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
for edge in nx_graph.out_edges(my_node):
   edge_type = nx_graph[edge[0]][edge[1]]['edge_type']
   if edge_type == 'foo':
       ...
```

Due to the many brackets this is not very easy to read...

A slightly more readable approach:

```
for edge in G.edges_iter(data=True):
    if edge[2]['edge_type']=='foo':
        ...
```

Yet it is still not very clear (especially the `[2]` ). Also, I am not sure how to use it with `out_edges()`

Comment: Regarding the part that I was "unsure how to use it with `out_eges`": I realized there is also an argument `data=True` so you can use the suggestion in the below answer from @Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option

```
for edge in ((u,v,data) for u,v,data in G.edges_iter(data=True) if data['edge_type']=='foo'): 
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I did not think of `u,v,data in G.edges_iter(data=True)`. Working with `data['edge_type']` instead of `edge[2]['edge_type']` and especially `nx_graph[edge[0]][edge[1]]['edge_type']` makes it more readable, indeed. Thanks!